# Drying properties of corn starch paste

Tags: adhesives, book-binding

In bookbinding different glues are used and the choice depends on their drying properties. From what I have read wheat starch paste is the traditional way to go. I want to produce my own paste and since it is easier to get I would like to use corn starch instead of wheat starch. In bookbinding one of the important questions is the colour the glue has in its dried state.

Is dried corn starch paste transparent or is it opaque? If it is opaque, which colour does it have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Corn starch paste **will dry transparently**, with a slightly warm tint.
You can use it for about a week.
As with all starch pastes, make sure to let it dry completely so it won't attract mold.

You can also look into using **rice starch/wheat as a basis**, for a more neutral dried colour and increased adhesive strength.

See [here](https://www.conservation-wiki.com/wiki/BPG_Lining#Adhesives) for an introduction to the differences between the types of paste.